# Anchor tag is not working

Tags: javascript, list

I used different anchor tags on my list but it is not working due to the JavaScript file attach to that list. when I remove that JavaScript file it works but I have to included my JavaScript too. Is there a way to used that same JavaScript file with anchor tag working?

```
function prepareList() {
     $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')
         .click(function (event) {
         if (this == event.target) {
             $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
             $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
         }
         return false;
     })
         .addClass('collapsed')
         .children('ul').hide();
     $('#expandList')
         .unbind('click')
         .click(function () {
         $('.collapsed').addClass('expanded');
         $('.collapsed').children().show('medium');
     })
     $('#collapseList')
         .unbind('click')
         .click(function () {
         $('.collapsed').removeClass('expanded');
         $('.collapsed').children().hide('medium');
     })
 };
 $(document).ready(function () {
     prepareList()
 });
```

I also attach `jquery-1.4.2.min.js` file as well

here is my html code:

```
<div id="listContainer">
            <ul id="expList">
                <li>
                    <p class="exp1">INDUSTRIAL</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <p class="exp1"><a href="fire-fighting-gallery.html">APPARELS</a></p>

                            <ul class="italic">
                                <li>
                                    <a>Coveralls</a>
                                </li>
                                <li >
                                    Uniforms
                                </li>
                                <li >
                                    <a href="fire-fighting-gallery.html">Aprons</a>
                                </li>
                                <li >
                                    Trousers
                                </li>
                                <li >
                                    Kevlar Lined Denim Jeans
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="exp1">GLOVES</p>
                            <ul class="italic">
                            <li >Seamless</li>
                            <li>Cut & Sewn</li>
                            <li>Leather</li>
                            <li>Mechanics</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            SLEEVES

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>


            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please prepare jsfiddle for this.

Comment: Without seeing this javascript file preventing your anchor tags from working people cannot help you. Can you edit your question with the relevant source code *or jsfiddle* please.

Comment: This is the ugliest code formatting I've ever seen posted on stackO.. if you really want help, please provide clear and easily readable materials. Use https://jsfiddle.net/ !

Comment: You need to provide your **full** HTML code, JS code in your question pinpointing the location where the error happens for others to understand and answer it.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience @urahara, I updated my ques

Comment: @nomeer I have posted my answer, the list is expanding now, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you the reason for the anchor tags not working without seeing the javascript file you have linked to your page.

If you place this after you include your javascript file, your links should be working as normal.

> If you have any anchors being created after the page has loaded *(dynamic data)* you can simply call `Links();` to apply the onclick event handlers or you can manually add `addEventListener('click',Anchors,false)`  when creating the anchor tag.

```
function Links(){
    //Get all Anchor elements
    var a=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    //Loop through each anchor element found.
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        //Set on click event for the anchor element
        a[i].addEventListener('click',Anchors,false);
    }
}
function Anchors(){
//Set new window location using the anchor href that triggers this function.
window.location.href=this.href;
}
window.onload=Links;
```

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave your comment(s) below.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You have screwed up `tag` id in :

```
 $('#expList') // <-- it was #expandList
     .unbind('click')
     .click(function () {
     $('.collapsed').addClass('expanded');
     $('.collapsed').children().show('medium');
 })
```

Check out here: https://jsfiddle.net/urahara/u809p5yr/

But it's still foggy to me what you are trying to accomplish, and how. Cheers ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with my web page. I post the workaround here in case anyone else is struggling with it.

In my case I've accidentally removed the class name from my javascript code and the function was triggering with every `<a>` tag in my page!!

The old one:

```
 $("a").on("click", function (e) {
    // ... my function ...
});
```

and the right way:

```
 $(".the-classname").on("click", function (e) {
    // ... my function ...
});
```

---

In your case I think the `return false` is preventing the  tag from working. Go ahead and delete it and check if it works fine.